AutoFill password into UITextField
I want to implement such a function: a password UITextField, using the system Jiugongge numeric keypad(textField.keyboardType = .numberPad), and enable to automatically fill the password. like this:
enter image description here
There's my code:
       let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
           let textField = UITextField()
           textField.placeholder = "password"
           textField.textContentType = .password
           textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
           textField.keyboardType = .numberPad.
           return textField
       }()

When I set textField.isSecureTextEntry = true, the button of autofilling password disappears, and if textField.isSecureTextEntry = false, the button of autofilling password appears.
When I set textField.keyboardType to other type like .default, and textField.isSecureTextEntry = true, the button of autofilling password also appears.
I wonder if that's Apple's feature? Is any way to make both textField.isSecureTextEntry = true, textField.keyboardType = .numberPad and the button of autofilling password appears?

Have you set your associated domains? According to the Apple Developer Documentation You have to have some domains associated with your app to have the AutoFill functionality.

When your app installs on an iOS device, the system attempts to
associate the app with all the domains listed in the app’s Associated
Domains Entitlement:
The system takes each domain from the Associated Domains Entitlement.
It tries to download the Apple App Site Association file
(apple-app-site-association) for that domain.
If all the steps succeed, the system associates the app with that
domain, and enables Password AutoFill for that domain’s credentials.


Even if I don‘t set any associated domain, autofilling password still appears when textField.isSecureTextEntry = true and textField.keyboardType = .default.

@ShilaiZhang As per your code snippet which you have added in the question, you have assigned "textField.textContentType = .password" due to which when textfield becomes first responder you are getting a suggestion of autofill password above numberpad keyboard.
